# Prove that $\int_A f d\mu = \int_E \chi_A f d\mu$.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I was reading Lebesgue Integration of arbitrary functions from my teacher's note.

> **Definition :** $f$ is a non-negative integrable function defined on a measurable set $E$, then we define the lebesgue integral of $f$ as $$\int_E f d\mu = \text{sup} \{\int_E s d\mu : s\le f \text{where s is a simple function}\}$$

And from here he straight went to some observations and one of the observations was :

> If $f$ is a non-negative measurable function defined on $(E, \sigma, \mu)$ and $A$ is a measurable subset of $E$. Then
> $$ \int_A f d\mu = \int_E \chi_A f d\mu $$

Now when I'm trying to prove it from definition I'm having a lot of difficulty. Just a reminder that the property of integral :

> $f$ is a non-negative measurable function defined on $(E, \sigma, \mu)$ and $A, B$ are measurable disjoint subset of $E$. Then
> $$ \int_{A \cup B} f d\mu = \int_A f d\mu + \int_B f d\mu$$

haven't been introduced by now. So I need a proof without the help of this result. Also I looked up at Royden and Rudin analysis books but I couldn't find any independent proof of these two properties.

Any help is appreciated.

**Note :** The function mentioned above is not necessarily bounded and the measure of the set $E$ is not necessarily finite.

Comment: What can you say about the simple function (that happens to be upper bounded by $f$), $s$, in the combination "$\chi_A s$"?  Still simple?  Still bounded by $f$?  Zero off of $A$?

Comment: In a sense, you're basically proving that result you say you can't use.

Comment: @Cameron yes you're right. That's the problem I'm facing. And I know that these two are interrelated results but there must be some way to work it out as my teacher has given it as a result not a definition so I need an independent proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The restriction operation :
$$\Big\{s:E\to[0,+\infty)~\Big|~ s \text{ is a simple function and }s\leq \chi_Af\Big\}\\\hookrightarrow \Big\{s:A\to[0,+\infty)~\Big|~s\text{ is a simple function and }s\leq f\Big\}$$
is a bijection, and for a non-negative simple function being zero off $A$, we have :
$$\int_E s\text d\mu= \int_As\text d\mu$$

Therefore, using the definition of the Lebesgue integral, we find :
$$\int_A f \text d\mu= \int_E\chi_Af\text d\mu$$

Comment: I might suggest avoiding the | notation for more complicated sets like this, or use one with some left and right padding (I forget which bar has the padding). As is, it's slightly cluttered. Good answer though.

Comment: Thanks for the feed back ! I added manually some space to make it look cleaner, and will look into how to do it properly in LaTeX/MathJax

Comment: Looks a lot better! I didn't know about `~` in $\rm\LaTeX$ code. Neat little trick. I've always used `\,` or `\quad` (or `\qquad`).

Comment: @SolubleFish can you elaborate your notations, I can't properly understand.

Comment: @Pritam basically it's a restatement of the excellent hint by Eric Towers expouned into a proper answer.

Comment: @Cameron okay let me think